# Is こんにちは a question?

Tags: greetings

I came across a cartoon of a Japanese lesson with

> こんにちは？

On a blackboard. Is the greeting actually a question? The impression I have (eg from [https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/今日は](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%BB%8A%E6%97%A5%E3%81%AF) ) is that etymologically speaking it's derived from a question, but wouldn't be regarded as a question nowadays.

Comment: Uptalk? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_rising_terminal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

こんにちは as a greeting don't have the meaning of a question. The origin is a phrase like 今日{こんにち}はご機嫌いかがですか?.

However some people may use こんにちは? as a question when they ask someone whether today is convenient for you or not, though きょうは? would be common.

Answer (score 0):

> こんにちは？

は、今｛いま｝でも疑問文｛ぎもんぶん｝かというのはおもしろい質問｛しつもん｝ですね。日本人[同士]｛どうし｝では話題｛わだい｝にすらならないと思｛おも｝いますが、たいていの日本人なら質問者｛しつもんしゃ｝が挙｛あ｝げた[文献｛ぶんけん｝](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%BB%8A%E6%97%A5%E3%81%AF)にある語源｛ごげん｝のようなことは知｛し｝っており、疑問符｛ぎもんふ｝がついていることも少｛すく｝なからず理解｛りかい｝しているのかなと想像｛そうぞう｝します。

真面目｛まじめ｝に回答｛かいとう｝しますと、**今｛いま｝では単｛たん｝なる挨拶｛あいさつ｝の言葉｛ことば｝であって、疑問｛ぎもん｝あるいは質問｛しつもん｝の意味｛いみ｝はないと思｛おも｝います（疑問｛ぎもん｝の意味｛いみ｝を持｛も｝たせずに使｛つか｝っています）**。

今回｛こんかい｝の質問｛しつもん｝は、漫画｛まんが｝の中｛なか｝でのことで、文脈｛ぶんみゃく｝も作者｛さくしゃ｝もわからないのでなぜ疑問符｛ぎもんふ｝をつけているのかに対｛たい｝する論評｛ろんぴょう｝は差｛さ｝し控｛ひか｝えます。
あらためてこの言葉｛ことば｝を考｛かんが｝えますと、話｛はな｝し言葉｛ことば｝としては普通｛ふつう｝に使｛つか｝いますが、作家｛さっか｝でもない私｛わたし｝を含｛ふく｝めた普通｛ふつう｝の日本人｛にほんじん｝は、これを書｛か｝くことはめったにないと思｛おも｝います。

もし、私｛わたし｝がこれを書｛か｝くとするとどうなるか考｛かんが｝えてみました。

1. こんにちは？
2. こんにちは！
3. こんにちは。
4. こんにちは、
5. こんにちは
6. 今日は？
7. 今日は！
8. 今日は。
9. 今日は、
10. 今日は

「こんにち」の部分｛ぶぶん｝に「今日」という漢字｛かんじ｝を使｛つか｝うと、「きょう」と読｛よ｝まれそうなで**なし**ですね。
どれも感心｛かんしん｝しませんが、敢｛あ｝えて選｛えら｝ぶと「こんにちは！」でしょうか。
これを使｛つか｝うのは、友人｛ゆうじん｝に送｛おく｝るメールの冒頭｛ぼうとう｝にでしょうか。それでも若干｛じゃっかん｝気恥｛きは｝ずかしいので、「こんにちは！」ではなく、「こんにちは！？」か「こんにちは（？）」のようにあらかじめ逃｛に｝げを打｛う｝つだろうと想像｛そうぞう｝します。それほど、これを文字｛もじ｝で書｛か｝き表｛あらわ｝すのは、実際｛じっさい｝には難｛むずか｝しいということでしょうか。

質問者｛しつもんしゃ｝への答｛こたえ｝になっていないようですみません。

「こんにちは？」の語源｛ごげん｝としては質問者｛しつもんしゃ｝が提示｛ていじ｝した文献｛ぶんけん｝にある意味｛いみ｝は比較的｛ひかくてき｝知｛し｝られていますが、参考｛さんこう｝までに、今回｛こんかい｝見｛み｝つけた[これも](https://ameblo.jp/hitomi-mazenda/entry-10723484415.html)私｛わたし｝にとって初｛はじ｝めての内容｛ないよう｝でしたが興味｛きょうみ｝深｛ぶか｝いものでした。

Comment: ご紹介の「これも」に目を通してみたが、その想像豊かな話や感覚、普通の日本人の間では、どれほど普及しているでしょうか。（あと一歩で天照大御神崇拝の復活になりそうな話にも思えたが．．．）

Comment: @Philippe: 今日様が太陽を表しているとは私も初めて知った話です。当然普通の日本人の間では普及していません。質問者が「こんにちは？」を質問に挙げたから、話題として提供したまでです。